Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'
enter image description here
i got a syntax error in there
slot1 = input.string("Piyasa Değeri",
    title="Slot 1",
    options=["Piyasa Değeri", "Kazanç Getirisi", "Fiyat Defter Oranı", "Fiyat Kazanç Oranı", "Fiyat-Satış Oranı", "Net Kar", "Brüt Kar", "Vergiler", "Satılan Mal Maliyeti", "Hisse Başı Kar"],
    group="Seçenekler")

i tryed using '' and '/' but they cant correct answers for this

It is an indexing error
replace the 4 spaces with two spaces
slot1 = input.string("Piyasa Değeri",
  title="Slot 1",
  options=["Piyasa Değeri", "Kazanç Getirisi", "Fiyat Defter Oranı", "Fiyat Kazanç Oranı", "Fiyat-Satış Oranı", "Net Kar", "Brüt Kar", "Vergiler", "Satılan Mal Maliyeti", "Hisse Başı Kar"],
  group="Seçenekler")

